# Scene redirects because previous scene receives updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I've been debugging this for hours, and can't seem to find the solution. 
For some reason, after using RouteActions to switch between scenes, a function from one of the previous scenes triggers and redirects the user.

The culprit seems to be a landing page screen that onComponentDidMount reads authentication tokens from AsyncStorage. Once that is said and done, the user will be redirected to the main screen (assuming credentials are valid). The authKey is stored in the local state

this.setState({'access_token':keyValues.access_token});

The reason I do this is so that I don't have to read the authKeys from AsyncStorage all the time. Anyways, that works all fine, and the user is directed through the app. Now two screens further down in the application, the user state is updated again, and because I added some console.log() statements, I can see that MapStateToProps in the authentication screen is being executed again, as well as a routing action that exists in the render() function of the authentication screen.

Do I need to remove the authentication screen from the stack? How do I prevent the state from updating (and calling ComponentDidMount) on a scene other than the one that is currently active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue: I was calling the RouteActions (using react-router-flux) within a conditional statement in the render() function of the auth screen. The authscreen stays on the scene stack when I navigate away from it, so the render function is called, even when the scene is not visible.

As a result, when the other screen fetched the auth token and updates the redux state (which was also connected to the auth screen), the RouteAction triggers.

So the fix was actually quite trivial: I put the RouteAction that caused the redirect, along with the conditional to check for presence of the access token inside the componentDidMount() function.